# what's the difference between autoencoder and autoassociative neural networks?

Tags: autoencoder

Seems like [Autoassociative neural networks](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009813549280051A) and [Autoencoders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) do the same thing.

Are they the same, or is there some subtlety I'm not picking up on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "autoassociative" paper is from 1992. The field had not settled on the term "autoencoder" for this concept.

Answer (score 1):

Autoencoders need at least 1 hidden layer to be constructed.

But, Autoassociative neural networks could be obtained through a bidirectional associative memory, which is implemented with no hidden layer, and whose weights are learned in one step.